# Redis Mass Insertion is not working with (error) ERR unknown command

Tags: redis

I am trying to upload data from text file with the example provided at https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert in Linux machine. My text file(testmass.txt) contains below data

```
*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n
```

when I execute below command

```
 cat testmass.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

Throwing error as below

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue. And one more thing, in that site, there is something related to RESP protocol. Do we need to install or run anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the actual `\r\n` characters - the escaped version can't be used like that. I.e. your file should look like:

```
*3<cr><lf>
$3<cr><lf>
SET<cr><lf>
$3<cr><lf>
key<cr><lf>
$5<cr><lf>
value<cr><lf>
```

Where  means "\r" (or ASCII character 13) and  means "\n" (or ASCII character 10).

Comment: Thanks Itamar, tried the same, but still getting error as below

(error) ERR unknown command '*3<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command '$3<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command 'SET<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command '$3<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command 'key<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command '$5<cr><lf>'
(error) ERR unknown command 'value<cr><lf>'

Comment: your file shouldn't have literal "\r", "\n", "<cr>" or "<lf>". It should have chars 10 and 13.